# Address a single page to SSL https secure protocol?

Tags: ssl, https

I need normal http on all the web site but I need only one with ssl socket.

I'd like to make a single page secure using https, is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) plugin to activate HTTPS on certain posts/pages on your website.

Install the plugin and you can use the 'Force SSL' option to force SSL on any page you want.

[image]

Comment: This plugin has been Updated: 4 years ago

Comment: True. But if you check the reviews section, you see that users are still using the plugin and it's functioning well. It's worth a shot, though.